# Is there something wrong with my json library in VS Code or is the json response invalid?

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to call a response from an API. I'm not sure what is wrong, maybe the response isn't valid JSON but I'm not sure. It doesn't seem the json module is initialising either. I've managed to call the data without json.loads(data) but I need to turn the response in to a dict so I can then use it in a formatted string e.g. print("Here are three suggested FAST terms for the {query}: ", {auth1}, {fast_id1}, {auth2}, {fast_id2}, {auth3}, {fast_id3})

Code:

```
### assignFAST
# https://www.oclc.org/developer/api/oclc-apis/fast-api/assign-fast.en.html
# http://fast.oclc.org/searchfast/fastsuggest?&query=[query]&queryIndex=[queryIndex]&queryReturn=[queryReturn]&suggest=autosuggest&rows=[numRows]&callback=[callbackFunction]

import json
import requests

### CALLING API
data = requests.get('http://fast.oclc.org/searchfast/fastsuggest?&query=hog&queryIndex=suggestall&queryReturn=suggestall%2Cidroot%2Cauth%2Ctag%2Ctype%2Craw%2Cbreaker%2Cindicator&suggest=autoSubject&rows=3&callback=testcall').text

data_text = json.loads(data)

print(data_text)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\0001255336\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\assignFAST\assignFAST_V1.py", line 10, in <module>
    data_text = json.loads(data)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\0001255336\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads 
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\0001255336\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode 
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\0001255336\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: The _presumptive_ response is that the request is invalid, but since you haven't shown it to us, how do you expect anyone to say how?

Comment: ...though given the details of the stack trace... are you sure that `data` isn't an empty string? You should probably look at it yourself, with your own eyes, before you go asking questions here :)

Comment: your input is not valid json

Comment: It's not valid JSON, because you've explicitly requested a non-JSON result.  Get rid of the `&callback=testcall` at the end of your URL.

Comment: removing callback... didn't help - still can't split the strings to use attributes to print     data_id = str(data).splitlines()[-10:-31:-10].split(',')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0):

There is a prefix in the response

```
data[:10]
'testcall({'
```

If you cut it out it works

```
data_text = json.loads(data[9:-1])
```

However it seems like the site does not work property because it doesn't deliver correct json

Comment: Thanks for confirming - this could be why I'm having trouble trying to work with the responses. I'll have to find a way to save and parse as text or something!

Comment: On the client site there is not much you can do. You could of course write an own interpreter but you can also automate it with something like `json.loads(data[data.find("{"):data.rfind("}")+1])`. I think the best approach would be to get valid json out of the API

Answer (score -1):

Because your json is not correct. Your variable data is of type string and therefore can't be loaded as json

[image]

Comment: What type of data do you believe CAN be loaded as json, other than a string?

Comment: The json response loads, python won't let me work with it, I can't make the json in to a dict to then use the variables, I split in to strings then the strings won't split further